# Can I get rid of the line that happens when I diagonally split with clip-path?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use clip-path to split a page using 2 layers, but a line appears (it's across the a in the view below). Both the left and right side is setup to clip on the same place. I'm thinking it's a rounding issue, but then wouldn't it round both the same way?

How can I make it perfectly clip?

```css
body > div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body > div > div{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #99cc00;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right > div{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
0 0, 70% 0, 40% 100%, 0 100%
  );
}

.left > div{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
100% 0, 70% 0, 40% 100%, 100% 100%
  );
}
```

```html
  <div class="left">
<div>
<img src=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7948781/mediapop.png>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
<div>
<img src=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7948781/mediapop.png>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Almost certainly rounding..and the broswer might be rounding down in both cases...perhaps a hacky 1px *negative* margin or transform?

Comment: @Paulie_D right but the line goes top to bottom between the same coordinates in both cases. Seems bizarre. I did however try to shift one layer in by the line remains it seems to be blurred or something.

Comment: Yeah...I played with it for a while any couldn't achieve much difference.